# Google Analytics PHP API : get reporting

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I have a professional website using Google Analytics for metrics and I try to automatize one task I used to do manually but.. not able to understand if it's possible ?!

I just began to using the Google PHP client library to access the Google Analytics API on my website [Test with the HelloAnalytics.php file](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php) is OK, I manage to connect and retrieve my data.

What i'm trying to do is :

- Get all URLs viewed in the past 24H (what you can see when you navigate in the GA dashboard -> Behavior -> Site content -> All pages)
- Combine those datas with my custom Definition which is in fact a special token i generate for every users on my website via PHP, then send it thought with Javascript and ga('set', 'mycustomdefinition', 'my token');

Is it possible ? 
Many thanks in advance for your support !

Comment: Yes, it is possible using the API.  Try it yourself and post your query on StackOverflow when you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Data under 24-48 hours old has probably not completed processing so I recommend not looking at data viewed in the last 24 hours it wont be correct.  Other wise yes you can see this.
2. Assuming you mean [custom Dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns) yes you can extract custom dimensions and the [page path](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath) in the same request.

You might want to have a look at the [Dimensions & metrics explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath) as well as the [google analytics query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) both will help you understand what data can be extracted from the API.

Comment: DaImTo thanks for uour help. When i use the Query Explorer tool i can choose my custom definition but I am unable to choose every page URL which has been viewed. I can chosse "**Page Value**", "**Pageviews**" and "**Unique Pageviews**" but those datas are not the one i need. There is a "**pagePath**" field but not in the metrics list, only in the "dimensions" field. Any help ?

Comment: pageviews will be the count of the pages viewed.   PagePath is the actualy web address.   There is a difference between metrics and dimensions.   You may want to play with until you understand how analytics data is stored.  This is NOT a relational database with columns and rows.

Comment: Ok, thx for your help. I undestand better now :) I manage to extract the datas i want !